# How to change laravel 8 pagination link format?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

laravel 8 pagination using this style for links

```
www.website.com/huawei?page=3
```

how i can make it like this?

```
www.website.com/huawei/3
```

Comment: Please share more details. Why not modify your route definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not specific way. so we need to play around the existing things.

But I had made it one of my application a long time before not tested much.

may be there is much better way also to achieve it.

so may it will work same for you. Please check below way to do it as pretty url.

**Route :**

```
    Route::get('/articles/page/{page_number?}', function($page_number=1){
    $per_page = 1;
    Articles::resolveConnection()->getPaginator()->setCurrentPage($page_number);
    $articles = Articles::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate($per_page);
    return View::make('pages/articles')->with('articles', $articles);
    });
```

**View** :

```
    $links = $articles->links();
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[] = '/'.$articles->getCurrentPage().'\?page=/';
    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[] = '';
    echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $links);
```

**Best Solution I had found :** Please use below package for laravel which help you.

https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-paginateroute